# Nested Query or Sub query linq

Tags: linq, nested

I have two classes. Bills and Transactions. One bill is made up of many transactions. I am able to display bills and I am able to display transactions on their own. But I would like to display the last 10 bills (this part is done), but each bill should show all its transactions.

```
This part of the code is used to get all transactions of a bill
{        Bill bill = (Bill)Bills.Instance.GetBillsByCustomerID(id);

                //get all transactions of bill
                var transactions = from t in this._entities.Transactions
                                   where t.Bill.bID == bill.bID
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       t.Product.pName, t.tQty, t.tUnitPrice, t.Bill.bTotal, t.Bill.bTimestamp, t.Bill.bCustomerIDF
                                   };
    }
```

Now I would like that the following query below, would have some sort of nested query where all transactions OF EACH BILL are obtained: (at the moment, this only displays 10 bills - and no transactions

```
{
            //returns top 10
            var bills = (from b in this._entities.Bills
                         where b.bCustomerIDF == id
                         orderby b.bTimestamp descending
                         select new { b.bTotal, b.bTimestamp, b.Customer.cName}).Take(10);
            return bills;
}
```

Can you please guide me to a simple solution? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want a `join` with an `into`

```
 var bills = (from b in this._entities.Bills              
              join t in this._entities.Transactions on t.Bill.bID equals b.bID into tg
              where b.bCustomerIDF == id
              orderby b.bTimestamp descending
              select new 
              { 
                b.bTotal, 
                b.bTimestamp, 
                b.Customer.cName,
                Transactions = tg
              }
             ).Take(10);
 return bills;
```

Comment: It seems to be working out :) All i need to do is to extract particular information for transactions now! Thanks a bunch

Comment: How is it possible to get only certain data for Transacations? for example tID (transaction ID) only?

Comment: @matfar92 - You would change the Transactions line to *Transactions = tg.Select(x => x.tID)*

Comment: thank you very much. at the moment I am trying to learn how to select many columns, eg. tID, tName, tQuantity etc! I hope I'll find a solution to that too! Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @matfar92 - If you want more than one column: *Transactions = tg.Select(x => new { x.tID, x.Property2, x.Property3 })*

Comment: Woow thank you very much for your help! I hope that it would be easy to display them in the gridview now! because for the transaction part,  I am writing DataField="Property2" but it is not being found :)

Comment: @matfar92 - I suggest you ask another question with your updated requirements

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that you should just be able to add something like the following into your select:

```
transactions.Where(x=>x.Bill.bID == b.bID)`
```

That having been said I do also think it sounds like your object model is wrong. I'd have expected a `Bill` to have a collection of `Transaction`s that are on that Bill.

Comment: It seems that from the first answer, a collection of Transactions is producted automatically for each bill!